# How to save data from form FileField to DB Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model and have added a Form FileField  to take a file and save all their contents for a particular object. The content from the file should be read, parsed, and stored to synonym_name of the model.

**model.py**

```
molecule = models.ForeignKey('MoleculeDictionary', blank=False, null=False)
synonym_type = models.ForeignKey('SynonymType')

synonym_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.synonym_name)
```

And this is how I add Form field to the models(admin)page.

**form.py**

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from django.forms import *
    import pdb
    import os
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
    from django.core.files import File
    from idg.models.molecule_synonym import MoleculeSynonym


    class MoleculeSynonymForm(ModelForm):
        file_upload = FileField(required=False)
        print "YES" 
        def save(self, commit=True):
            print 'saving...'
            file_upload = self.cleaned_data.get('file_upload', None)
            file_upload.seek(0)
            with open("../../Downloads/model_file_upload.txt", 'r') as f:
                model_file = File(f)
                names = model_file.read()
                print(names)

                form = MoleculeSynonymForm(names)

                return super(MoleculeSynonymForm, self).save(commit=commit)
            #

        class Meta:
            model = MoleculeSynonym
```

I have two questions:

1. How should I save the names to the Synonym_name for a chosen synonym_type and molecule. I use sqlite. My current code doesn't throw any errors other than:

> The molecule synonym "" was added successfully.

2. How do I get the "full path for the file" without hardcoding them in the open statement.

**Update: tried this :**
I know this could be downright stupid :

```
 try:
    synonym_name = MoleculeSynonym.objects.create(synonym_name=names)
 except:
    synonym_name = None

    print synonym_name

    synform = MoleculeSynonymForm(instance=synonym_name)
```

print statement prints None.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what you are trying to this but if this helps have a look:

```
class MoleculeSynonymForm(ModelForm):
    file_upload = FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MoleculeSynonym

    def clean_file_upload(self):
        file_upload = self.cleanded_data['file_upload']
        if file_upload:
            model = YourModel()
            model.file = file_upload
            model.save()
        else:
            raise errors
```

Replace YourModel with your model and file with your model file field.

Comment: I want to update the database with "content of the file " not the file. Secondly, using the file_upload gives me error "Can't find the file file_upload". That's the reason I used the hardcoded path of the file.